# C++ (win)OpenSSL MD5 Crash

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, md5

I have been stuck for a day now on implementing openssl(on windows) md5.  Such a simple thing seems like its taking forever.  It crashes @ MD5_Update when ran.  Is there something I am missing, and if I am, any helpful tips to improve my code so I never do it again?  I followed these documents: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html  Thanks.  I really do appreciate it.  :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[] = {0xd1, 0x31, 0xdd, 0x02, 0xc5, 0xe6, 0xee, 0xc4, 0x69, 0x3d, 0x9a, 0x06, 0x98, 0xaf, 0xf9, 0x5c};
    unsigned char hash[16];
    MD5_CTX *c;
    MD5_Update(c,data,16);
    MD5_Final(hash, c);

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (int)hash[i] << " ";

    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to use `MD5_Init(c);` before `MD5_Update`?

Comment: Yes. You do. Thanks for the swift response! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never create, nor do you allocate space to hold, the MD5 context.

```
MD5_CTX *c;
MD5_Update(c,data,16);
```

You can't use a variable before you assign it a value! After your first line, `c` has some arbitrary junk value, which you then pass to `MD5_Update`!

Try:

```
MD5_CTX c;
MD5_Init(&c);
MD5_Update(&c, data, 16);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It works!  I forgot to add: MD5_Final(hash, &c);

Comment: Hash some known data and check the output. The MD5 hash of "0123456789abcdef" (16 characters, ASCII, lowercase) is "4032af8d61035123906e58e067140cc5".

Comment: unsigned char data[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66};  I am getting: 0x43 0xb8 0x4a 0x8e 0x08 0x1a 0x16 0x62 0x05 0x50 0xbf 0x13 0xe9 0xd3 0xe3 0xb5

Comment: Gah I thought you meant only the letters.  It works now: unsigned char data[] = {0x30, 0x031, 0x32, 0x33, 0x034, 0x035, 0x036, 0x037, 0x038, 0x039, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66};  Sorry for being a pain!